# Android Gradle Build takes too much time

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[image]

My Gradle.Properties File

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
kotlin.code.style=official
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.caching=true
kapt.incremental.apt=true
kapt.use.worker.api=true
```

and Here is my Gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Mon Apr 12 20:55:45 IST 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1-all.zip
```

And Here goes the app Build.gradle File

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}
android {
    compileSdk 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mysmitch.care"

        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.0.24"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        relasesigningkey {
            try {
                storeFile file('D:\\Smitch Projects\\Smitch Care\\keystore\\keystore.jks')
               
            }
            catch (ignored) {
                throw new InvalidUserDataException("You should define KEYSTORE_PASSWORD and KEY_PASSWORD in gradle.properties.")
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
           splits.abi.enable = false
           splits.density.enable = false

            resValue "string", "app_name", "SMC DEBUG"
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://a*******************/\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "SYMPTOMS_URL", "\"https://a*******************/v1/\"")
        }
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            resValue "string", "app_name", "SM CARE"
           buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://a*******************/\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "SYMPTOMS_URL", "\"https://a*******************/v1/\"")
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.relasesigningkey
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/DEPENDENCIES', 'META-INF/LICENSE', 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt', 'META-INF/license.txt', 'META-INF/NOTICE', 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt', 'META-INF/notice.txt', 'META-INF/ASL2.0', 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is build analizer tool in AS ... Without project itself  it's impossible to said what causing long build ... it can be anything starting from low PC spec

Comment: @selvi I have a decent PC spec.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest code to compile is no code. I would suggest trying to remove plugins, dependencies, settings, etc, one at a time. See what improves the speed and what makes it worse. If it speeds up the compilation can you live without it?